# Dynamic buttons in UIAlertController (iOS 8)

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

I try to create and remove buttons on UIAlertController (with action sheet style) dynamically. I can create the UIAlertController and add button to it. No i want to clear all buttons and add other buttons but couldn't find any method to clear the buttons. Anyone has experiences with this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just dismiss the first alert controller, then make a new one and present it afterwards?

Comment: actually no, I didn't think about that :D. It's actually very simple solution for my problem. I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a new `UIAlertController` with your new set of buttons, then present it immediately after dismissing the first one. You can play around with the options for animations and `UIViewControllerTransitioning` if you're not happy with the default animations.

Comment: This is a good article to read if you want to try using custom transitions: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/